# Visual Studio Redo shortcut Ctrl + Y stops working after copy

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am working on Visual Studio 2010 . I did some changes in code but then wanted to see how a block of code looked like before editing .
So I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> undo and then proceeded to copy the intended block of code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
Now when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> , then redo is not done and all my changes are lost.

Please help me out.

Comment: This works fine for me - I suspect you accidentally typed something when doing the copy or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you cannot redo something when you make a change after your undo.

A redo is only available if the previous command was an undo. Copying code into the editor will clear the ability to redo. Only the undo command will be available after a paste action.

Comment: so no solution to this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is common in all applications with undo/redo functionality. I would suggest copying your code before the undo into a text editor for short term safekeeping.

Comment: now i am messed up ... but that doesn't mean i won't give you +1

Comment: However, if your code that you performed the undo on was copied within Visual Studio, it may still be in your circular clipboard. This is accessed through Ctrl + Shift + V.

Comment: @RobAston Surely a Ctrl+C does not count as a change though? I've tested it in Visual Studio and if I type some text, undo, Ctrl+C, then redo it then my typed text reappears... +1 for the circular clipboard in the comments though - you should put that in your answer :)

Comment: Do a web search for terms such as "visual studio clipboard ring" or for "clipboard manager".

Comment: @RB. I think the action of copying in this scenario could have included an accidental key press meaning the redo command will become unavailable.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Timeline Tab]

If you had previously saved your file, then you can access previous versions of your file from the Timeline tab in the bottom left corner, which has the Local History of files. You can also view the previous version if you did Ctrl + Z (Undo) and accidently saved the file and cannot do Ctrl + Y (Redo) now.

Answer (score 2):

Did you know that you can copy multiple lines of text and then view them from your clipboard by doing the keyboard shortcut **Windows + V**. This could have been a handy option you could have used to overcome this issue.

Comment: this saved my day, and countless hours of my future, thank you!!